# System allow to add single address multiple times in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

System allow to add single address multiple times.

```
 Step -
    → Login with valid user credential in magento frontend.
    → Tap on “Address book” from My Account.
    → Then click on “Add new address”.
    → Enter valid information in field and tap on “save” button more then one time.
    => System save same address multiple times.
```

can any buddy help me to solve this issue.. user should click only one time on save button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help in future to someone else, user fill up valid value in form and only once he/she will be able to click on submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('my-form-id', true);   

    var formAlreadySubmitted = false;
    $j('#my-form-id').submit(function(e){
       if(dataForm.validator.validate()){
          if(formAlreadySubmitted){
             e.preventDefault();
                return false;
             }
             var submitChildren = $j(this).find('button[type=submit]');
             submitChildren.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             submitChildren.addClass('disabled');
             formAlreadySubmitted = true;
        }
    });

//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have customized it, try to check if there is multiple forms on that page.